# Retrieve instantiated types from UnityContainer

Tags: c#, unity-container

(Using Unity 4.0.1)

Given a UnityContainer object, is there any way to retrieve all the objects that have been instantiated by the container up to that point in time? E.g. something like

`IEnumerable<object> instantiatedObjects = unityContainer.GetAllInstantiatedObjects();`

or, even better, filtering according to those that derive from a given type:

`IEnumerable<IFoo> instantiatedFoos = unityContainer.GetAllInstantiatedObjects<IFoo>();`

Comment: The actual instantiated objects depend on the lifetime they are registered with. What exactly do you think you need this for? [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: One option would be to write a wrapper around `UnityContainer` implementing `IUnityContainer` that stores any objects that get instantiated (for you to query later). What are you trying to achieve though, as it's likely there is something in Unity's lifetime management that will do what you want already...

Comment: RB - A wrapper would only be able to store the root-level instantiated objects. Whereas I'd also want to be able to retrieve any objects further down the dependency graph that the `UnityContainer` instantiates.

Comment: XY Problem - In my case, you can assume that all the registrations have been done using a `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`, i.e. the instances are singletons managed by the container. The reason I'm asking for this is because I want to be able to (selectively) call some methods across all instances within the container that implement a particular interface, for diagnostic and memory management purposes.

Comment: You could probably write a [Unity strategy that would fire on PostInitialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178462(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec10). From memory, these will get fired for all dependency resolutions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [RB's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49114346/retrieve-instantiated-types-from-unitycontainer#comment85234629_49114346), the following approach [implements a custom Unity extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178462(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec10) with a strategy that keeps a reference to each instantiated object upon PostInitializtion.

N.B. The following code is for illustration only, and is not intended to be thread-safe/exception-safe etc.

First, the implementation of the Extension class and other classes it relies on.

```
public class ObjectContainer
{
    private readonly List<object> _instantiatedObjects = new List<object>();
    public void Add(object instantiatedObject)
    {
        _instantiatedObjects.Add(instantiatedObject);
    }
    public IEnumerable<object> GetInstantiatedObjects()
    {
        return _instantiatedObjects;
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> GetInstantiatedObjects<T>()
    {
        return GetInstantiatedObjects().OfType<T>();
    }
}

public class InstantiatedObjectsStrategy : BuilderStrategy
{
    private readonly ObjectContainer _objectContainer;
    public InstantiatedObjectsStrategy(ObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        _objectContainer = objectContainer;
    }
    public override void PostBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        _objectContainer.Add(context.Existing);
    }
}

public class InstantiatedObjectsExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    private readonly ObjectContainer _objectContainer = new ObjectContainer();
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Context.Container.RegisterInstance(_objectContainer);
        Context.Strategies.Add(new InstantiatedObjectsStrategy(_objectContainer),
            UnityBuildStage.PostInitialization);
    }
}
```

The extension can be added to the UnityContainer immediately after creation:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddNewExtension<InstantiatedObjectsExtension>();
```

The instantiated objects can then be retrieved from the container at a later stage as follows:

```
IEnumerable<object> instantiatedObjects = container.Resolve<ObjectContainer>().GetInstantiatedObjects();
IEnumerable<Foo> instantiatedFoos = container.Resolve<ObjectContainer>().GetInstantiatedObjects<Foo>();
```